# Limit with complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I've never calculated limits with complex numbers before. Why does

$$ \lim_{z\rightarrow \infty} \frac{e^{3iz}-3e^{iz}}{z^3} =0?$$

This is contrary to my intuition, since exponentials grow faster than powers.

Comment: Is $z$ complex or real number in the question. If it is real, then using the Euler formula the top is bounded. If it is complex, the limit cannot be zero as seen in the case $z=-it$ with $t$ real going to $+\infty$.....

Comment: @MikeMiller something..

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $t\to+\infty$ on the real axis and $z=-it$.  Then we have
$$
\frac{e^{3iz}-3e^{iz}}{z^3} = \frac{e^{3t} - 3e^t}{it^3}
$$
and that does not approach $0$.

This complex-valued function has an essential singularity at $\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $t$ real we have

$$ e^{3it}-3e^{it} =\cos(3t)-3\cos(t)+i(\sin(3t)-3\sin(t))$$

which is a bounded function:

$$\left| e^{3it}-3e^{it} \right| \leq \left| \cos(3t) \right| +\left|-3 \cos(t) \right| + \left| i\sin (3t) \right| +\left| -3i \sin(t) \right| \\ \leq 1+3+1+3=8$$

The intuition that exponentials grow faster than polynomials is true for **real** exponentials. The complex exponentials are bounded in the imaginary direction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm tryng to calculate $ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{ \sin^3}{x^3} \,dx$ with x=real variable. It was told me that I have to consider it as a particular case of the complex case. Than, I have expressed the sinus in the exponential form and tryed to close the path to apply the residue theorem.. But it was told me that I can apply it only if the limit (for z->infinity) of the function that I want to integrate is 0....

Comment: So I want to prove that the function that I have posted in the question goes to zero for z->infinity. To answer to the question that you posted in your comment,I'd say that z is real.. am I wrong? Many thanks!